# copy file from one path to another with a 'variable folder name' in the path - batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file, path, copy, directory

I got a problem in copying a file from one path to another path with a 'variable folder name' in the path

The following code works fine if the folder name doesnot have a space in it.(hear Folder1 is the variable folder name)

CODE:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET inpu="Folder1"
::SET /p fil=enter file name: 


for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir "C:\Users\kumark3\Desktop\"%inpu% /ad /b') do (
set /a userslen+=1
set "usersarray!userslen!=C:\Users\kumark3\Desktop\%inpu%\%%x"
)


for /l %%x in (1,1,%userslen%) do (

xcopy "!usersarray%%x!\geth\gr.txt" "C:\Users\kumark3\Desktop\Folder2" /c /h /r /y /i

)
```

But if the folder name has a space, the code is not working
for eg if the 2nd line in the code is like

SET inpu="Folder 1"

Please give me a solution for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost done, change quotes positions in

```
set "inpu=Folder 1"
```

and

```
'dir "C:\Users\kumark3\Desktop\%inpu%" /ad /b'
```

EDITED - To answer to comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "inpu=Folder 1"
    set "where=C:\Users\kumark3\Desktop"

    for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /ad /b "%where%\%inpu%" /ad /b') do (
        set /a "userslen+=1"
        set "usersarray!userslen!=%where%\%inpu%\%%x"
    )

    set users

    for /l %%x in (1,1,%userslen%) do (
        xcopy /c /h /r /y /i "!usersarray%%x!\geth\gr.txt" "%where%\Folder2" 
    )
```

Comment: Still not getting the answer

Invalid number of parameters is the error am getting

Comment: @user3173444, see updated answer. Where are you getting your invalid number of parametes?